# Angular LifecyleHooks and when is @ViewChild valid?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lifecycle

I am a bit perplexed.  I thought I basically understood the lifecycle of angular components, but THEN I ran into an interesting case, where the @Input of a component was undefined.

In this case, **I have TWO instances of my application**.  The given component: **LogoutWarning** is shown when a logout is pending and the user can then refresh the login token and continue.  That works fine.

The instance comes up when the first application renews the login token, and hides showing the **LogoutWarning** component. All is good in this first application.

The second application is also showing the **LogoutWarning** component since it detected the login token was going to become expired and shows a **LogoutWarning modal**,  It then notices that the login token was been renewed and calls LogoutWarning.cancel() to hide the modal.  In this case, this.logoutWarningModal.hide() explodes because the this.logoutWarningModal is **UNDEFINED**, even though the lifecyle ngAfterViewInit() shows that this.logoutWarningModal is defined.

I am an very surprised at this point.  If I simply check that this.logoutWarningModal is undefined and not call this.logoutWarningModal.hide() all works as expected. But why is this.logoutWarningModal undefined here???

The code for the **LoutWarning** component is simple:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'logoutWarning',
  template: `
    <div bsModal #logoutWarning="bs-modal" [config]="{ show: true }" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="new application version avaliable" aria-hidden="true" (onHidden)="hidden()">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <div class="app_header">
              <div class="app_icon"><img src="assets/images/tracker_hi_res_512.gif"></div>
              <div class="app_name">Tracker</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body center-message">
            <span class="bold">You will be logged out in </span>
            <span><strong>{{minutes | async}}</strong> minutes!</span>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="ok()">Stay Logged In</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
`
})
export class LogoutWarning implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('logoutWarning') public logoutWarningModal: ModalDirective;
  @Input() minutes: string;

  constructor(private userCondition: UserCondition, private broadcaster: BroadCaster, private versionS: Version, private auth: AuthService) {
  }

  public ok(): void {
    this.auth.renewLogin(this.userCondition, this.userCondition.minutesDurationUntilLogout.getValue());
    this.logoutWarningModal.hide();
   }

  public cancel() {
    if (this.userCondition.bShowLogoutWarning) {
        this.logoutWarningModal.hide();
    }
  }

  public hidden() {
    // reset the state of the dialog so that it can be reshown.
    this.userCondition.bShowLogoutWarning = false;
    this.logoutWarningModal.show();
  }


  public ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ngOnInit()');
    console.log('this:', this, this.logoutWarningModal);
  }

}
```

and the component is shown when userCondtion.bShowLogoutWarning is true and shown in my main application.  The relevant section of html is:

```
<logoutWarning *ngIf="userCondition.bShowLogoutWarning" [minutes]="userCondition.minutesUntilLogout"></logoutWarning>
```

Both applications log:

```
 ngOnInit()    logoutWarning.component.ts?f8b4:55 
 this: LogoutWarning {userCondition: UserCondition, broadcaster: BroadCaster, versionS: Version, auth: AuthService, logoutWarningModal: ModalDirective, …} 
 ModalDirective {onShow: EventEmitter, onShown: EventEmitter, onHide: EventEmitter, onHidden: EventEmitter, isAnimated: true, …} 
    userCondition.service.ts?0111:164
```

Then after the first application renews the login token, the second application shows:

```
 this: LogoutWarning {userCondition: UserCondition, broadcaster: BroadCaster, versionS: Version, auth: AuthService} undefined
```

where this.logoutWarningModal is UNDEFINED!

Thanks for your insight!

Answer (score 11):

@ViewChild would return `undefined` till it's initialised and it's the case in OnInit(). Check it in AfterViewInit() instead:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
   console.log('ngAfterViewInit()');
   console.log('this:', this, this.logoutWarningModal);
    // this will returns the object
}
```

Comment: The really strange issue is that the component is already initialized and OnInit has been called. But the call in my app.module seems too be calling the initial LogoutWarning component from the provider specified when the app is bootstrapped.    Is there a way to insure that only one instance is created and shared k